# How to get the contents of a script tag in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium with C#. I have code which returns me a script tag as an `IWebElement`. How do I get the content from it?

Comment: Did you try using the `.getAttribute("script")` on your `element`?

Comment: Thanks, yes, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best you can do is use `GetAttribute` and access it's `innerHTML`.

```
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Regardless of your age (and if you're not who I think you are, you're probably quite confused), this is absolutely spot on. Thanks.

Comment: @David, some say it's impossible to find someone who's younger than me ;) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("script"));
String htmlCode = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

P.S. is in Java but you can do same in C# with some small edit.