# Can Selenium 2 verify SCRIPT tag

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I'm new to using Selenium 2 (via the Firefox Plugin) -- I haven't found this answer elsewhere on the net.

Is it possible to verify if a `<script>` element is **present in the code of a page**?

I need to frequently check a number of pages that require a range of **script links** and **on page script block elements**.  I haven't been able to figure this part out. One example is to check to see if the **Google Analytics** script is on a page.
Here's the sample code that is expected:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||'
   function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),

 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'xx-x-0000-00', 'somedomain.com');
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This answer suggests you can use can use `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497607/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-script-tag-in-selenium

Comment: I'm using the Selenium IDE Firefox Plugin to create the HTML script.  How / Where would I include the use of the getAtribute?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution? @Richard - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium IDE, you can get attributes like so:

```
<tr>
<td>storeAttribute</td>
<td>//script@innerHTML</td>
<td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${x}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

You may need a better selector for the `<script>` element.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Trying what you suggested.  Not getting desired result. Get error messages when using code such as:

    <tr>
 <td>storeAttribute</td>
 <td>//script[contains(@src, 'filename.js')]</td>
 <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>echo</td>
 <td>${x}</td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>

The error message is: [error] Invalid xpath [2]: //script[contains(

Can you use my example as reference, given that it is located in the HEAD of a page.   Thanks!

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but not sure if this is the proper code.  I figure I can duplicate this for each script I need to test for:  <tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>xpath=//script[@src='//path-to/script/location.js']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr> IS THIS CORRECT?  It fails if I run it against a page known not to have the script present - thus proving it validates.

Comment: @photoman I'm only passingly familiar with Selenium IDE, but that looks right from the reading I've done.