# Save generated HTML using Canopy

Tags: html, f#, web-scraping, save

Can a website's *generated* HTML be saved using Canopy? Looking at the documentation under ['Getting Started'](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/), I could not find anything related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run arbitrary JavaScript using `js`, `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will return the current DOM, so

```
let html = js "return document.documentElement.outerHTML" |> string
```

does the trick.

Comment: While your answer looks and behaves promising, the problem is that it returns the generated HTML code of the default WebDriver page, i.e. "<html><head><title>WebDriver</title>˛</head><body>..." and not that of the specified URL, which seems to take some time to load. Inelegantly adding some `Thread.Sleep` and looping to wait for the target HTML to load throws `NoSuchWindowException`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no (single) solution to that problem. In general, you cannot tell whether a page (including JavaScript) has finished loading / executing or whether there are some actions waiting (e.g. through `setTimeout`) or even just infinite animations. If you know the page you can wait for some indicators: see `waitFor`, `waitForElement`, e.g. `waitFor (fun () -> js "return document.readyState" |> string = "complete")`
Anyways, this should be a separate question (probably going to be closed as duplicate).

Comment: In fact I overlooked the [required configuration for IE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration). With everything set, and your `waitFor` code, it can indeed save the _generated_ HTML. Much thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Canopy is a wrapper around Selenium that provides some useful helper functions. But it also provides access to the Selenium `IWebElement` instances in case you need them, via the [`element` function](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/actions.html) (halfway down the page; there don't seem to be internal anchors in that page so I couldn't link directly to the function). Then once you have the `IWebElement` object, your problem becomes similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497607/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-script-tag-in-selenium/20498102#20498102), where the answer seems to be `elem.getAttribute("innerHtml")` where `elem` is the elememt whose content you want (which might even be the `html` element). Note that the `innerHtml` attribute is *not* a standard DOM attribute, so this won't work with all Selenium drivers; it will be dependent on which browser you're running in. But it apparently works on all major Web browsers.

See [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python) for a related question using Python, which has more discussion about whether the `innetHtml` attribute will work in all browsers. If it doesn't, Canopy *also* has the `js` function, which you could leverage to run some Javascript to get the HTML you're looking for -- but if you're having trouble with that, you probably need to ask a Javascript question rather than an F# question.

Comment: When I try to add `let html = element "html" |> string`, it throws `NoSuchWindowException`, which is strange, since there should be an html element in the generated HTML page.

Comment: What happens when you load that page in a browser, then open up the Developer Tools to look at its contents? Does it have an "html" element?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `|> string` there? The idea is to get hold of the `IWebElement` **object** and use its properties; converting it to a string seems counterproductive.